# preg_replace regex for replacing anchor tag where URL is not sample.com

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regex for preg_replace which replace anchor tag where some URL(e.g. sample.com) exists in href. Now what i need is a regex which will replace all other anchor tags which does not contain some URL(e.g. sample.com).

Here is my regex:

```
$rw     =   "Go to hell";
$message    =   "<a href='http://twitter.com'>Twitter</a><br/><a href='http://google.com'>Google</a><br/><a href='http://facebook.com'>Facebook</a>";
$message   =   preg_replace("/<a[^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*'(?:[^']*google.com[^']*|[^][^']*facebook.com[^']*)'>(.*)<\/a>/siU", $rw, $message);
```

Result is:

```
Twitter (with link)
Go to hell 
Go to hell
```

What i need:

```
Go to hell
Google (with link)
Facebook (with link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex pattern as shown below(using *lookahead negative assertion* `?!`):

```
...
$message = preg_replace("/<a[^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*'https?:\/\/(www)?(?!(google\.com|facebook\.com))[^']*'>(.*)<\/a>/siU", $rw, $message);

print_r($message);
```

The output will be:

```
Go to hell
Google (with link)
Facebook (with link)
```